# Kafka min insync replica vs acks

Tags: apache-kafka

If my topic has min-isr=2, replicationfactor = 3, Producer has acks=all.

1. Suppose if both the replicas are lagging the leader (not down, but have not caught up) and the Producer posts a new message.
   Will that message even be accepted by Kafka or will it throw a NotEnoughReplicas exception (or another)?
2. Case 2: If 2 replicas are in sync (including the leader), will the acknowledgement be sent back to the producer after all 3 have caught up? Or will it be sent as soon as the 2 ISRs have acknowledged the message?

Thanks

Comment: - 1/ if lagging to the point of being outside of the ISR (see [replica.lag properties](https://www.conduktor.io/kafka/kafka-options-explorer/?search=replica.lag)), then NotEnoughReplicas will be thrown (because of min.isr=2 not respected)

- 2/ acks=all cares only about ISRs, so the ack will be sent back after the 2 ISRs acknowledged (the leader and the follower in-sync)

Comment: For #2, this link https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_acks says for acks=all
'This means the leader will wait for the full set of in-sync replicas to acknowledge the record. '. Hence the question.

Comment: Yes, "the full set of in-sync replicas" = ISR. In your example, it's a set of 2 (leader+one follower)

Comment: The producer has request timeout config, by the way. So, it won't wait forever for the ack

Comment: So you mean to say the “Current set of ISRs”? In my example there are 2 followers & 1 leader. so total Replicas are 3. But InSync are 1 Leader and 1 follower.

Comment: One more possibility. Total Replicas - 4, InSync-3, Min-ISR=2. In this case is the ack sent after 3 acks based on above comments ?